# eval `ssh-agent` for cap deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano

I'm on ubuntu 11.10. When I need to deploy using capistrano, unless I write

```
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add
```

the deploy process asks for the git repository password as well as the server access password.  Can I set something in my terminal config to stop me having to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can able to solve your issue by using ssh public/private key, I think following references helps you to solve it.
[capistrano problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176544/capistrano-problem), [Capistrano asks for password when deploying, despite SSH keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269578/capistrano-asks-for-password-when-deploying-despite-ssh-keys)